# How to exit mootools each()

Tags: javascript, mootools, exit, each

How can I exit the each function when the conditions was true once?

This does not work:

```
  $$('.box div').each(function(e) {
 if(e.get('html') == '') {
    e.set('html', 'test');
    exit;
 }
  });
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`.some`](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.6.0/Types/Array#Array:some)?

```
  $$('.box div').some(function(e) {
     if(e.get('html') == '') {
        e.set('html', 'test');
        return true;
     } else
        return false;
  });
```

But probably you could just use

```
  arr = $$('.box div[html=""]');
  if (arr.length > 0)
     arr[0].set("html", "test");
```

Comment: +1 What a flippin' good idea!! (Took the liberty of adding a link to the docs.)

Answer (score 1):

Just `throw` something and `catch` it higher:

```
try {
  $$('.box div').each(function(e) {
    if(e.get('html') == '') {
      e.set('html', 'test');
      throw "break";
    }
  });
} catch (e) {
  if(e != "break") throw e;
}
```

But using a combination of `.every` and `.some` would be a far better idea.